# nuxt page middleware does not run on server first when pressing browser's back button

Tags: vue.js, nuxt.js, server-side-rendering

I have a page middleware where I am fetching some data for a feature flag. The middleware / flag works fine when navigating to the page within the application, but if I navigate back to it using the browser's back button, it errors out because ssrContext is not defined, presumably because the middleware is running on the client first and not the server. Is there any way to get the server middleware to run first upon navigation using the browser's back / forward buttons? Thanks!

```
<template>
  <h1>Page I want to render</h1>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  async middleware({ redirect, ssrContext }) {
    // ssrContext is undefined when navigating with browser's back button, causes and error
    // otherwis works perfectly whilst nabivigating with the app's nuxt-links
    const featurEnabled = await ssrContext.$featureFlagClient?.getValueAsync(
      "featureEnabled",
      false
    )

    if (!featureEnabled) {
      redirect(`/`)
    }
  },
}
</script>
```

Comment: no there is not, ssr only happens on initial hitting the page from the server and refresh etc, not though a nuxt link, you would need to place all featureEnabled items into store first time around then if (process.client) {// look up feature enabled } or make an endpoint for it